# capture the exact moment when user click allow for browser geo location request popup window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, geolocation, promise

I uses `window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` to obtain the status of a user permitted use of geo location from browser or not. However, I found there is a significant delay on my angularjs app to see the exact moment when the 'allow' is been detected. I am using angular to detect that with its own `$window` instead of `window` for easy dirty checking. However, it usually result in a delay of 2s or so after user click on the allow, only then, the angular detects my broadcasted message of `browser-geo-location-permitted` , because the broadcast fire only after getCurrentPosition is executed as a promise.

```
$window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('browser-geo-location-permitted');
})
```

So I wonder is there something wrong with detection I made this way or there is a more instant way to capture the exact moment user clicked on "Allow" for browser geo location request? I am open to pure js solution as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to be notified of when the user allows geolocation. You will only be notified of when the browser has determined the position of the user.